# Event description is not getting added in Google Calendar using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm adding events in Google Calendar using Google Apps Script and following the example I added the events like this:

```
var summary = "Some description";
var otherArgs = {description: summary};
        var event = calendar.createEvent(
          title,
          new Date(parseDate(startStrDate, startTime)),
          new Date(parseDate(endStrDate, endTime)),
          otherArgs
        );
```

But when I see the event in Google Calendar there is an empty desciption.

If I hardcode it like

```
var event = calendar.createEvent(
          title,
          new Date(parseDate(startStrDate, startTime)),
          new Date(parseDate(endStrDate, endTime)),
          {description: "Some description"}
        );
```

I get the same result.

Comment: What happens if you hard code the option?`var event = calendar.createEvent(          title, new Date(parseDate(startStrDate, startTime)),new date(parseDate(endStrDate, endTime)), {description: "Some description"}
 );`

Comment: If I hardcode it like you say I get the same result.

Comment: Try `{description: "Dinner at 5PM"}`

Comment: It seems like a bug.  You can report it on the Issue Tracker:  [https://Issuetracker.google.com](https://Issuetracker.google.com)